# How could I set up perl 5.10.1 on a Debian Lenny machine to be the default perl for all users (except for root and system processes)?

Tags: debian, installation, perl

I am going to create a new Virtual Machine running Debian Lenny. I want to install the latest stable version of Perl (5.10.1) such that all non-root users would use it by default. However, I don't want to mess up the system perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution: [How can I install a separate perl without disturbing the existing one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527259/how-can-i-install-a-separate-perl-without-disturbing-the-existing-one). I guess that I just didn't use the right search terms yesterday.

UPDATE:
See [perlbrew](http://search.cpan.org/dist/App-perlbrew/) by Kang-min Liu. It allows you to easily install multiple versions of perl without disturbing the system perl.